# how to use Navigator push to goto page1 to form3

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, pageviews

I try to build a demo app with using PageView and bottomNavigationBar. My problem is how to use Navigator push or pop and navigate from page 1 to form 3. User any time can cancel the procss only form1, form2 or form3.

Example page layout

```
AccountsSummary
    page1
        form1,
            form2,
                form3
    page2
        form1,
            form2,
                form3
    page3
        form1,
            form2,
                form3
```

Question how to use Navigator push to goto page1 to form3…

```
new Scaffold(
  body: new PageView(
    children: [
      new AccountsSummary(
          index: this._page,
          niyaziUserNo: "${widget.niyaziUserNo}"),
      new CardsSummary(
          index: this._page,
          niyaziUserNo: "${widget.niyaziUserNo}"),
      new TransfersSummary(
          index: this._page,
          niyaziUserNo: "${widget.niyaziUserNo}"),
    ],
    onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
    controller: _pageController,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
    child: new BottomNavigationBar(
      items: [
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
          title: new Text(“Accounts”,),
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.credit_card),
          title: new Text(“Cards”,),
        ),
        new BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.language),
          title: new Text(“Transfer”,),
        ),

      ],
      onTap: navigationTapped,
      currentIndex: this._page,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: For PageViews, use a `PageController` instead of the navigator.

Comment: You can user namedRoutes too.

Comment: yes true about PageController and I did in my app. My problem is how to navigate from Page1 to Form3 and cancel or return back. All the form gets user input data, and when its cancel or goes to back I guess I need to see despose all the variable. Also, I believe I need to use form or scaffold key. any small example?